# Bootstrap css column items not inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this html:

```
<div id="table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
    <label>
        <div id="datatable-search-input-container">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="search" class="datatable-search" placeholder=" Search" aria-controls="table" id="datatable-search-input">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search UserName">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Phone Number">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 clearfix" id="datatable-controls">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <span class="datatable-control-item">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="searchButton">Search</button>
                </span>
                <span class="datatable-control-item">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="resetButton">Reset</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

It generates an a search function like this:

[image]

If you take a look at the image, for some reason, my col-sm-3 columns take up an entire row instead of going inline. I have checked the css and nothing is overwriting the widths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to wrap your `col-sm` classes in a `row` one.
Like this

```
<div id="table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
  <label>
        <div id="datatable-search-input-container" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="search" class="datatable-search" placeholder=" Search" aria-controls="table" id="datatable-search-input">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search UserName">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Phone Number">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 clearfix" id="datatable-controls">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <span class="datatable-control-item">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="searchButton">Search</button>
                    </span>
                    <span class="datatable-control-item">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="resetButton">Reset</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

If you use Bootstrap 4 (as it seems you are) and you want all the columns to have the same size you also don't need to specify the number, so you could just use `col-sm`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to ensure that each input is evenly spaced? Seems like the col-sm declarations have a padding that spreads everything out too much

Comment: It could be because you use `col-sm-3` so the blocks are expected to take 12/3 = 25% of the whole space. Bootstrap is based on a 12 columns system.
But go over their doc a bit, you should find a lot of help there: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/